# How to write regex to change the go keywords color?

Tags: regular-expressions, font-lock

I want to change the  color which in `package import go defer` in go-mode ,need a regex..these code only change the `pacakge` word color

```
    (defface my-font-lock-gokeyword-face
    `((t (:foreground "#ab4642"))) ;; change to desired color
    "Face for go keyword.")

    (font-lock-add-keywords 'go-mode
    ;; change to desired operator regex
    '(("package"  0 'my-font-lock-gokeyword-face)))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want all keywords to be fontified differently, or only a subset?

Comment: The question remains unclear, so I've voted to close it.

Comment: My best guess is that you simply want to `M-x customize-face RET font-lock-keyword-face` and change the colour of that pre-existing face to something you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If you change "package" to "^package.*" I think it will match every line that starts with package to the end of the line. I don't know enough about go to know if that is always the right thing to do here.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,i update the comment. you can see this pic ,i think its better.

Comment: I don't get what you want. You just want the package word in another color than it already is?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, just add the other keywords to the list. Something like:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'go-mode
;; change to desired operator regex
'(("package"  0 'my-font-lock-gokeyword-face)
  ("go"  0 'my-font-lock-gokeyword-face)
  ("defer"  0 'my-font-lock-gokeyword-face)
  ("package"  0 'my-font-lock-gokeyword-face)))
```

I understood you want the same color for all four keywords, then this is fine. Otherwise you can change the faces to whatever color you want for the keywords.